# PL/SQL ORACLE: Trigger for months_between isn't doing anything

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

So I have two tables, people and reservation. When a person tries to make a reservation but the difference between the day he wants to register and the day the reservation opens is greater than 2 month, then an error should be shown on the screen that says u r reserving too soon for this. Here is the trigger I made: (NOTE: PEOPLEID in the reservation table acts as a foreign key)

```
create or replace trigger reservings 
    before insert OR UPDATE on RESERVATION
    for each row
declare
vdate   DATE;   
vadd  number;
begin
select date_to_register into vdate from PEOPLE WHERE PEOPLEID=:NEW.PEOPLEID;
    vadd:=TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(vdate,:NEW.RESERVATIONDATE));
    if INSERTING AND vadd>2 then 
      Raise_Application_Error (-20343, 'ITS TOO EARLY');
      ELSIF UPDATING AND vadd>2 then
      Raise_Application_Error (-20343, 'ITS TOO EARLY');
    end if;
    end;
```

So when I run this, the trigger gets compiled but when I enter a date for when a person may want to do the reservation and when the reservation date actually is and there is clearly a difference of greater than 2 months, it still allows the data to be entered rather than throwing the error. Whats happening? :/
heres what I insert on RESERVATION TABLE:

```
INSERT INTO RESERVATION(ID,PEOPLEID,RESERVATIONDATE) VALUES(1,1,(TO_DATE('11/12/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY')));
```

Comment: What a result this query returns: `select date_to_register from PEOPLE WHERE PEOPLEID=1;`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that `MONTHS_BETWEEN` returns negative value if second argument is greater than first argument.

You need to use `MONTHS_BETWEEN(:NEW.RESERVATIONDATE , vdate)` if you are always sure that `vdate <  :NEW.RESERVATIONDATE`.

Else , use `ABS()` function on your expression if you are only interested in a difference of 2 months.

something like `...ABS(vadd) > 2 ..`